# How to rewrite on nginx?

Tags: nginx

My problems is rewrite url on nginx config.

I have url: `http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.jpg`
document root: `/home/myuser/web`
filename.jpg stored on `/home/myuser/uploads/folder3/filename.jpg`

Now i need check if file `/home/myuser/web/uploads/folder3/filename.jpg` exist then rewrite to this file
or not exist then rewrite to url  /index.php?r=folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.jpg

Note: only use my url and i don't want to redirect url
Please help me.
Thanks advanced

Comment: If read docs can working for all that no need Stackoverflow. Please follow example about that

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked for. If the file does not exist, the URI is internally rewritten to `/index.php?r=/folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.jpg` (with a leading `/`).

```
location /folder1/folder2/folder3/ {
    alias /home/myuser/web/uploads/folder3/;
    try_files $uri /index.php?r=$request_uri;
}
```

EDIT: In the case where *folder1*, *folder2* and *folder3* are placeholders for a regular expression. Obviously *folder3* must be a physical directory within the document root. The regex location below will match a wide range of patterns and should be placed near the bottom of the `server` block to avoid interfering with more specific regex location blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

```
location ~ ^/[^/]+/[^/]+(/.+)$ {
    root /home/myuser/web/uploads;
    try_files $1 /index.php?r=$uri;
}
```

Comment: folder1 2 3 dynamic. unable to set with multiple location